# Проверка нескольких условий в Bash

Tags: bash

Имеется скрипт, который должен проверять наличие FILE1 и FILE2 и если оба файла существуют, запускать другой скрипт /usr/bin/script. Но, если какого либо файла нет, файлы должны создавать командами command1 и command2 соответственно.
Например:

```
if [ ! -f "$FILE1" ]; then
    command1
elif [ ! -f "$FILE2" ]; then
    command2
    /usr/bin/script
else 
    /usr/bin/script
fi
```

Скрипт работает, если нет ни одного файла или оба существуют, но если удалить FILE1, то при последующем выполнение скрипта, файл создастся, но /usr/bin/script не запустится.

Как сделать, что бы создавались недостающие файлы и после запускалась /usr/bin/script ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если нет файла FILE1, то выполнение заходит в ветку if и после создания файла вся конструкция завершается, в ветку else выполнение не заходит. Нужно вынести `/usr/bin/script` за пределы if, т.к. тот скрипт должен выполняться в любом случае:

```
if [ ! -f "$FILE1" ]; then
    command1
fi
if [ ! -f "$FILE2" ]; then
    command2
fi
/usr/bin/script
```

Comment: При такой конструкции не выполнятся command2 при первом старте, если запустить еще раз command2 отрабатывает. Для запуска /usr/bin/script требуется наличие сразу FILE1 и FILE2

Comment: Да, верное замечание. Но в вашем варианте command2 тоже не выполнится. Подправил.